# How to get previous adjacent element by class?

Tags: javascript

There are several elements with `article-text` in the page, but I want to grab the one that is located just above the share button. 
The html looks like this:

```
<div class="article-text">
 This is not intended to be grabbed
</div>

<div class="article-text">
  Text to be grabed
</div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com&text=:%20http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com&via=mySite" target="_blank" title="Tweet" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title) + ':%20'  + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + ' ' +encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByClassName('article-text').previousSibling)); return false;">

<div class="article-text">
 This is not intended to be grabbed
</div>
```

This it returns `undefined`. I've also tried `document.getElementsByClassName('article-text')[0]` but that grabs the page url instead. So I'm clueless and appreciate your help.

Comment: Where is the `share` button in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.previousElementSibling`, `.textContent`, `.trim()`

```
encodeURIComponent(this.previousElementSibling.textContent.trim())
```

```html
<div class="article-text">
 This is not intended to be grabbed
</div>

<div class="article-text">
  Text to be grabed
</div>

<a href="#" target="_blank" title="Tweet" onclick="console.log(this.previousElementSibling.textContent.trim())">

<div class="article-text">
 This is not intended to be grabbed
</div>
```

Comment: I accepted the answer because it neatly answer the problem as I described above. but in fact it did not work for me because there are some elements (other buttons, etc.) between the share button and the `text to be grabed`. Is there still a solution in this circumstances?

Comment: Fantastic. I could not make it in a year!

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function(e){ 
    var shareBtn = document.getElementById("share").previousSibling;
    console.log(shareBtn)
    
}
```

```html
<div class="article-text">
 This is not intended to be grabbed
</div>

<div class="article-text">
  Text to be grabed
</div>

    <a id='share' href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com&text=:%20http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com&via=mySite" target="_blank" title="Tweet" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title) + ':%20'  + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + ' ' +encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByClassName('article-text').previousSibling)); return false;">

<div class="article-text">
 This is not intended to be grabbed
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you want to use the twitter link as your share button. So I will set to an id=share so it's easier to find then with jquery selector link 
      $("#share")
 you can just call it to do whatever you want

your code after the edit :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="article-text">
 This is not intended to be grabbed</div>

<div class="article-text">
  Text to be grabed
</div>
<div id="share">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com&amp;text=:%20http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com&amp;via=mySite" target="_blank" title="Tweet" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title) + ':%20'  + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + ' ' +encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByClassName('article-text').previousSibling)); return false;">
</div>
<div class="article-text">
 This is not intended to be grabbed
</div>
 </a>
```